# Readonly ObservableCollection having an element added mysteriously

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

C# Application, WPF, MVVM Model

So I have an ObservableCollection *items*.
Items doesn't have a setter defined, only a getter, which calls of to a service to get a fresh collection from the DB backing this application.

Now in the viewmodel for a page we have something like:

```
{
    Public viewmodel(){
    items.CollectionChanged += CollectionChangedEvent;
    List<item> display = new List<item>;
    }

    private void CollectionChangedEvent(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){
    updateDisplay();
    }

    private void updateDisplay(){
         display.clear();
         foreach(item i in items){
             display.add(i);
         }
    }
}
```

So where it gets tricky is that when a user presses a button that updates an element inside items. The event handler gets called, then somehow items gets an addition *identical* copy of the item added in, then the event handler gets called twice more, updating the display again, but this time without changing items. Now the display has two identical items on it. Infact, if you change one of the items, the other changes with it.

If I remove the event handler and only update the display manually, it works fine, updateDisplay doesn't change the observablecollection items.

Is there a common pitfall I might be missing here? The more I dig into this the deeper the rabbit hole goes.

Comment: 1. I'll bet money something is happening in code that you left out. 2) `display` should be a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`. When you create it, after `items` is instantiated, pass `items` to its constructor. You're reinventing that wheel; no need to.

Comment: Can you show your XAML? I have a feeling that there might be a second call through binding.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to "genericize" this code for *reasons*.

However, I took your suggestion of making display a ReadOnly that's get method creates a new readonly pulling from items. No effect, still have the same problem. Which of course XAML only binds to the ReadOnly display, so it can't be there,

Comment: Well, this doesn't look bizarre.  I'd wager you could radically simplify this code and remove the bug, but I can't exactly tell what you're doing here.  I've written a ton of wpf apps and have never had to watch an observable collection and copy its members out somewhere.  That's just plain weird :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this sounds like a Threading issue. Event handlers can get called from different threads, so it sounds like your "items" and "display" items are not getting synced up correctly.

Try the following:

```
private Object _lock = new Object();

private void CollectionChangedEvent(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    updateDisplay();
}

private void updateDisplay()
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        items.CollectionChanged -= CollectionChangedEvent;

        display.clear();

        foreach(item i in items)
        {
            display.add(i);
        }

        items.CollectionChanged += CollectionChangedEvent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work in the sense that I'm not receiving duplicate items now, but I am receiving an exception that you cannot modify an ObservableCollection inside ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged Event handler.

Comment: just to confirm "items" is your ObservableCollection, right?

Comment: Yes. Items is the observable collection, and display is whats bound to a WPF element.

Comment: If you are adding items to a bound collection of type "List", it will not update on the UI. Can you post the exact exception you are getting? Sounds like you will either need to Invoke the Add or "copy" the collection

Comment: I got it through the stack trace. Treading carefully what was happening was two collectionchanged events were being raised, for a remove and an add, the backing element to items couldn't handle the remove event when it was empty. Thanks for the help though --  it certainly led to the answer!